# having trouble with custom http headers in django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to post json data through a view to be processed and put in a view.  The json contains a custom header named x-pinpoint-token. However, when I try and get this data through request.META.get it cannot get the data I need.

```
class Data(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(IDFAData, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        token = request.META.get('X_PINPOINT_TOKEN')
        if token is None:
            return HttpResponse(
                "Failed Authorization - 401",
                status='401'
            )
        else:
            token = token.split(':')
            token_clean = token[1]
        data_in = json.loads(request.body)
        ...
```

No matter what I pass through the view token seems to be empty.

A test I ran with `python-requests`:

```
import requests
token = '8756990800504b3f86a103bba1a03aab'
token = 'Token:'+token
data_in = {...}
import json
headers = {}
headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
headers['X_PINPOINT_TOKEN'] = token
payload = json.dumps(data_in)
r = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/', headers=headers, data=payload)
```

but it just returns 401.

Comment: Note that request.META is supposed to be a normal Python dictionary, so you can log it or print it or enter pdb or so to check its contents easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `HttpRequest.META`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) says:

> HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name.

So try `request.META.get('HTTP_X_PINPOINT_TOKEN')`.

(An easy way to debug this would be to print or log `request.META.keys()`.)